# Is it safe to delete unnecessary user metadata?

Tags: database, user-meta

I'm having performance issues with my Wordpress site, due to the number of registered users, the `wp_usermeta` table has almost 70 million rows.

Users do not have access to modify their profile so I have thought about deleting the unnecessary metadata that Wordpress creates when registering a new user. The following rows are created for a normal user:

```
+----------------------+------------------------------+
| meta_key             | meta_value                   |
+----------------------+------------------------------+
| nickname             | [USER_NICKNAME]              |
| first_name           |                              |
| last_name            |                              |
| description          |                              |
| rich_editing         | true                         |
| syntax_highlighting  | true                         |
| comment_shortcuts    | false                        |
| admin_color          | fresh                        |
| use_ssl              | 0                            |
| show_admin_bar_front | true                         |
| locale               |                              |
| wpe_capabilities     | a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;} |
| wpe_user_level       | 0                            |
| default_password_nag |                              |
| session_tokens       | [SESSION_DATA]               |
+----------------------+------------------------------+
```

I have thought of deleting all rows except `nickname` and `session_tokens`. Will i have a problem if i do this? Is there a way for Wordpress to not create these rows for new users?